# How to properly position buttons inside a grid-layout to be responsive

Tags: html, css

I am using `react-strap` [cards](https://reactstrap.github.io/components/card/). In the application I have a lot of cards like the print-screen below.

**The problem** is that it does not look very good because as I shrink the application all the buttons do not preserve a proper position and instead of wrapping nicely they seem to have a strange position.

Below is how the card is structured:

[image: layout]

**App.js**

```
        <div class="btn-toolbar">
            <Row>
                <Col>
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" role="button" href={example2}>
                        Project Notes
                    </a>
                </Col>
                <Col>
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" role="button" href={example2}>
                        Location Map
                    </a>
                </Col>
               {/* Other Cols... */}
            </Row>
            <Row style={{ marginTop: '20px' }}>
                <Col>
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" role="button" href={example2}>
                        Borrow Area Info
                    </a>
                </Col>
                <Col>
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" role="button" href={example2}>
                        Solicitation
                    </a>
                </Col>
               {/* Other Cols... */}
            </Row>
        </div>
```

**App.css**

```
.btn-primary {
    display: inline-block;
    text-decoration: none;
    letter-spacing: var(--mainSpacing);
    color: var(--mainBlack);
    background: var(--shadowGreen);
    padding: 0.4rem 0.9rem;
    border: 3px solid var(--shadowGreen);
    transition: var(--mainTransition);
    text-transform: uppercase;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

**What I have done so far:**

I think the problem might be in the `.css` file. I don't have any settings in particular for that because I don't know if the card can be affected other than the one I posted above. Is the problem due to a missing grid-layout? If so How can I fix that so that the buttons can wrap nicely when I shrink/enlarge the application?

Thank you very much for pointing to the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of what i mean.

```css
.cardcontainer
{
  width:100vw;
  margin-bottom:20px;
}

.buttoncontainer
{
    width:100vw;
}

.button
{
  float:left;
  width:25%;
  margin-bottom:20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cardcontainer">
   <img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/813011/pexels-photo-813011.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" alt="Italian Trulli">
</div>

<div class=buttoncontainer>
  <div class="button">
     <button type="button">Button</button> 
  </div>
   <div class="button">
     <button type="button">Button</button> 
  </div>
   <div class="button">
     <button type="button">Button</button> 
  </div>
   <div class="button">
    <button type="button">Button</button> 
  </div>
</div>
```

And a fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/4mfpr8kv/

Comment: You can then use a media query for phones to change the button containers width on smaller screens.

Comment: 100vw means the containers take 100% of any screen size

Comment: Perfect! Thank you very much for the small example, that really helped solving the problem. It works now! :)

Comment: glad i could help :)

Answer (score 0):

You have no fixed widths or heights set on your css.

I would say use a parent div with the width and height you need, then use CSS to detect media screen size and adjust the width based on the screen sizes.

Then for your cards set the width and height to 100% of the parent div, then this will keep its scale and other items will wrap nicely around them.

Then for the buttons set each of them inside a parent div, set the parent divs width as well, with media screen statement.

Then  each button should be wrapped in a container, with a width of 25%% and float left. Then the buttobs will scaled and adjust nicely.

Comment: Thanks for reading the question and for the suggestion :). Could you please integrate some code that explains your solution? That would be good to understand your suggestion.

Comment: Certainly, will give you a fiddle of something similar :)